# How to create an ordered list starting by 01

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, slim-lang

I am working on a rails app where I loop over `tuto`

```
    .container
      .row
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-12
          h1.text-gray Tutorials
          br
        .col-xs-10.col-sm-5.index-background
         - @tutos.each do |tuto|
            ol.h4.text-white
              li
                h4.text-white = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto)
```

I found out this solution, it starts from `01`as expected...

```
ol {
list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
}
```

But it render all the lines with 01.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My`ol`was not at the right place , just moved it a little bit above :)

```
 .container
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12
      h1.text-gray Tutorials
      br
    .col-xs-10.col-sm-5.index-background
      ol.h4.text-white
        - @tutos.each do |tuto|
         li
           h4.text-white = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto)
```